# Google Sign-In for Websites Documentation Frustration and "gapi.auth2 has been initialized with different options." error

Tags: javascript, google-authentication

I'm so frustrated by the google auth docs. They seem to be inconsistent.

It says here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initparams

I can call

```
gapi.auth2.init(params)
```

In my case, I want to pass in the `hosted_domain` param to restrict who can sign in to this app. Under the parameters list it explicitly states that

"You must request the `email` scope when using the `hosted_domain` parameter alongside `fetch_basic_profile: false`."

Great so I come up with:

```
var apiKey = 'my_key';
var scopes = 'email name';
var GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.init({
    apiKey: apiKey,
    fetch_basic_profile: false,
    scope: scopes,
    hosted_domain: "my_domain"
});
GoogleAuth.signIn()
    .then(function(response) {
            // Do stuff
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

When I test this out I get an error in my console:

`gapi.auth2 has been initialized with different options. Consider calling gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() instead of gapi.auth2.init().`

But the docs clearly state that I should send the params to the `init()` method.

So I go to the getAuthInstance() documentation:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2getauthinstance

Where is explicitly states that

`You must initialize the GoogleAuth object with gapi.auth2.init() before calling this method.`

Um, that's exactly what I thought I did, so why the error telling me to go straight for the `getAuthInstance()`? This is making me molt.

So I give it a try:

```
var apiKey = 'my_key';
var scopes = 'email name';
var GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance({
    apiKey: apiKey,
    fetch_basic_profile: false,
    scope: scopes,
    hosted_domain: "my_domain"
});
GoogleAuth.signIn()
    .then(function(response) {
            // Do stuff
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

And the result is not as expected. It essentially proceeds to ignore the hosted_domain allowing anybody to sign in and seems to retrieve the full profile rather than just the email and name. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: The params don't look right. I've got an app with domain restriction and all it has is `gapi.auth2.init({client_id: clientId, hosted_domain: domain})`. That's all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the note for the `hosted_domain` param. You don't **need** to set `fetch_basic_profile` to `false` but if you do, you need to add *"email"* to the `scope` param.

As far as I can tell, this is all you should need...

```js
const apiKey = 'my_key';
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
  gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: apiKey, // note "client_id", not "apiKey"
    hosted_domain: 'my_domain'
  }).then(auth2 => { // wait for initialisation
    if (!auth2.isSignedIn.get()) { // check if already signed in
      auth2.signIn().then(...)
    }
  })
})
```

---

As for your error...

> gapi.auth2 has been initialized with different options. Consider calling gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() instead of gapi.auth2.init().

Sounds like you may be calling `gapi.auth2.init()` in multiple places. There should only be one instance of this.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your replies. Your answers make sense to me and I realize I made a mistake in that apiKey should be client_id. I made those changes and still get the same console error :-(

Comment: Oh also your right I think I misunderstood and thought it was saying I needed to set `fetch_basic_profile` to `false`. In hindsight your explanation makes better sense.

Comment: According to this example its apiKey...

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests

Comment: According to here its client_id... 

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2getauthinstance

Comment: @JonathanSN the former example is for the _"client"_ library, not the _"auth2"_ library. _"auth2"_ definitely only uses `client_id`

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarifying. So I still don't understand why I'm getting this error...

Comment: @JonathanSN did you see my edit above? I suspect you have multiple calls to `init()`

Comment: Okay! I figured it out. I had other references to gapi that were being called BEFORE `gapi.auth2.init()` (in another module) which was causing the problem. **Be certain that `gapi.auth2.init()` is the very first thing to be called or you will get this error.**

Otherwise, Phil's answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @SOreadytohelp sorry I didn't see your latest post until just now. I guess I didn't refresh my browser. Sorry. You were correct.